# Programmatically get String Keys for LookAndFeels

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

Firstly, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519951/location-of-string-keys-in-lf) question, which I know sounds a lot like my question, but I do have a slightly different question. From my research, I have found that some L&F's have different `String` keys than others, and I want to know how to set each value of the L&F using `UIManager.put(String key, Object value)`.

The problem is that some L&Fs require different keys than others, and I am looking for a way to equate each property of each L&F so that I may programmatically set each value. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243020/uimanager-how-to-get-values-of-different-lookandfeels), which says how to get a value from a key using `UIManager.getColor("key")`, but don't know how to get the keys.

I also found [this](https://github.com/tips4java/tips4java/blob/main/source/UIManagerDefaults.java), which uses `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();`, but when I print out the objects in it, it produces a load of gobbledygook that I can't really use to find the keys (maybe this is how to find the keys, if you can figure it out, kudos to you).

I put [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128291/how-to-make-a-swing-application-have-dark-nimbus-theme-netbeans) question's code into my own code, since it provides some of the keys. Here is the code I used:

```
UIManager.put( "control", new Color( 128, 128, 128) );
  UIManager.put( "info", new Color(128,128,128) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusBase", new Color( 18, 30, 49) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusAlertYellow", new Color( 248, 187, 0) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusDisabledText", new Color( 128, 128, 128) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusFocus", new Color(115,164,209) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusGreen", new Color(176,179,50) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusInfoBlue", new Color( 66, 139, 221) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusLightBackground", new Color( 18, 30, 49) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusOrange", new Color(191,98,4) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusRed", new Color(169,46,34) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusSelectedText", new Color( 255, 255, 255) );
  UIManager.put( "nimbusSelectionBackground", new Color( 104, 93, 156) );
  UIManager.put( "text", new Color( 230, 230, 230) );
```

I like the Nimbus theme for my project, however, I want to be able to switch the L&F within the application and be able to switch between the similar keys for each different L&F. Like I said, some keys may be different between L&F's for the same value used in the L&F.

Comment: You can assemble the defaults as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953657/230513) by @camickr, but you'll have too infer correspondence.

Comment: I followed that link and it took me to a link I already had in the question, what part of that code is the part I need to find the keys?

Comment: The answer directly below the one in that question is part of the answer to my question, it lists all the different keys for a particular L&F, but doesn't say how to translate between the keys from one L&F to another.

Comment: There is no canonical translation; each L&F defines the keys it uses.

Comment: So what you're saying is, that if I used the code from the answer in the question above, and made a 2D array of Strings, I could use an ID variable and switch between the L&F's? Or are there different amounts of keys between different L&F's?

Comment: Run the demo cited to see the disparities. Pick a component and key; change the L&F; some match; some don't.

Comment: But are there the same amount of keys and values for each L&F?

Comment: No; each L&F defines the keys it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should print the keys of the currently used L&F:

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
Enumeration<Object> keys = defaults.keys();
Collections.list(keys).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```